# https connection works over Wifi (wlan) but not for 3G/GPRS (umts)

Tags: android, https, timeout, wifi

I find this kindda strange: I transferred a working http connection into a https connection with a self-signed certificate following [these instructions](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html). All works well when I'm connected to WiFi. However, 3G/GPRS connections won't work. Instead, I get a 'timed out' or 'connection refused' exception.

So does *anyone* have an explanation for this? Any help is appreciated since this is time critical.

Thanks in advance,
steff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, you guys were so right in pointing me to the certificate issue. Actually I couldn't believe it and it's still not clear to me how it worked over WiFi and failed over 3G on some devices while working on others even though all being on the same carrier.

Anyhow, my university validated the certificate and i can't believe it's actually working. Thank you so much. Without you I think I would have lost it...

Regards,
steff