# Volley Request over https only works with Wifi (wlan) but not for 3G/GPRS (umts)

Tags: android, ssl, https, wifi, android-volley

Because I was instructed to ask this issue in my own question I'm doing this here.
To see [Original Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172857/https-connection-works-over-wifi-wlan-but-not-for-3g-gprs-umts) in which I first asked my question (deleted now).

I got stuck with the same Problem and unfortunately the answers of the author aren't helpful.

To introduce my issue a little bit more in detail, I work with a self signed certificate on my Tomcat 8 (v8.0.15) server on the internet with Java 8 (v8.0.25 - JDK). There I host my Java EE Application, which is the backend for my Android Application. The SSL connector of the Tomcat works as it should. When I test the backend with a [RESTClient](http://restclient.net/) I get the result as expected.
I created the keystore with one certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore 
-storepass MYKEYSTOREPASS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365
```

Then I extracted the certificate:

```
keytool -export -alias tomcat -storepass MYKEYSTOREPASS 
-keystore tomcat.keystore -file tomcat.cer
```

Lastly I created a new Keystore in the BKS format for my Android Application:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file tomcat.cer -keypass MYKEYSTOREPASS 
-keystore tomcat.bks -storetype BKS -storepass MYKEYSTOREPASS 
-providerClass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
-providerpath $PATH_TO_BC_LIBRARY/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar
```

> (as mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) the "-export" and "-import" parameter are from previous
>   releases but still useable. So you could also know this command
>   parameters as "-exportcert" and "-importcert")

After finishing this steps I tried to connect and everything went fine. But only till I deactivated/left my WLAN connection. Then it did not work any more and brings an "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate". 
I really do not understand this behaviour.

To brighten up the android side a little bit more:
I used the classes/library from [this tutorial](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-android-volley-with-self-signed-certificate/) in exact the same way.

If something is missing, just comment and I will bring the infos.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you using local tomcat server?

Comment: Hi Suhail Mehta, I edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "located in the www", does it mean that is on some server that is external to your wifi network?

Comment: Yes its external to my wifi network. (I edited my question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While making my research on Server Fault for similar issues I got a hint what could be wrong also:
https://serverfault.com/questions/560733/why-isnt-tomcat-serving-the-correct-ssl-certificate
I tried it out with the missing parameter "keyAlias", and it worked! The solution was finally - like Ogre_BGR expected before - a not optimal tomcat configuration. The connector looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE"
           keystorePass="PASSWORD_FOR_YOUR_KEYSTORE"
           keyAlias="ALIAS_OF_YOUR_CERTIFICATE"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           />
```

Tomcat silently picks only the first key it finds in the keystore, when no keyAlias is configured. Mentioned in the docs [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) (at the bottom).

I hope that some day somebody will be glad to read this, while having the same Problem.

Thanks again @Ogre_BGR :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a server configuration problem. I am not sure how Tomcat works but probably it is similar to Apache where you declare one virtual host for the "normal" requests (i.e. non https) and one virtual host for the HTTPS (which includes the SSL cert). Usually each virtual host is binded to one IP. It is quite possible that when you are accessing your server via WIFI that you get some "internal" IP like 192.168.* and probably you configured your virtual host to bind to that ip.

When you are accessing via 3G you go trough the "public" network and then the IP of the server is different, so the virtual host does not match, e.g. SSL certificate is not used and you get "No peer certificate".

I suggest that you will have to check the server configuration and logs and see how the server is accessed by either method.

Comment: I connect via absolut URLs to my Server. Something like this: `HTTPS://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8443/APP/rest/bla/foo` The connector is binded to this Port (8443), so the SSL is used every time.
Just to give an example:
I make a call from an computer in an completely foreign network of the same URL (`HTTPS://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8443/APP/rest/bla/foo`) as in the Android App and I get my result. But with the APP on my Smartphone it does not work over 3G.

I got what you answered, but I'm not sure if this would make sense. Because my example is pretty much the same and provides a counterexample.

Comment: Just to clarify: you use selfsigned certificate with "Common Name" (FQDN) your IP, or some domain/subdomain?

Comment: Yes, I use a self signed certificate with the ip of my server als name, the other meta-informations are empty.

Comment: The only possible reason for the different results from the RestClient and Android is because the RestClient is working as browser plugin and thus it is using its certificate chain which is different from the built-in in android. That means that probably your server is not using your selfsigned certificate at all. Please open your URL from normal browser and inspect the certificate used. There is a big chance that it uses some other certificate (at least in some cases).

Comment: btw, using IP in the selfsigned cert is not very good idea. Back in time I had exactly the same problems as you now just because wifi network used some weird routing and the result was that the server was hit on some local IP (and the cert did not matched). Best solution is to use some subdomain in the cert.

Comment: I checked your instructions and opened my server url with a normal Browser, checked the (SHA-1) fingerprint of the cert and opened the keystore on server side with `keytool -list -keystore PATHTOKEYSTORE -storepass KEYSTOREPASS` to check the fingerprint from this side. The result: they are equal, both have the same fingerprint. One thing to mention: the JKS Keystore for my Tomcat displays in the line with the alias and the create date "PrivateKeyEntry", where the BKS Keystore displays "trustedCertEntry". Is this sth. unusual?

Comment: The last thing that I able to suggest is to open the URL from browser on the android device. First over wifi and then over 3g. Take a look at the certificate if it differs. About the PrivateKeyEntry/trustedCertEntry - seems OK.

Comment: I'll try open the website over WIFI, when I get access to it. 3G is already tested. The result: I can't display the website. I think this is due the self signed cert right? Or should FF on my Android device be able to display it?

Comment: If it is properly set on the server you should be able to see the site both over wifi and 3g. Also in both cases you should see warning that certificate is not trusted (because it is selfsigned) (or at least it will say so in the cert details). My advise is to ask on Server fault how to check the tomcat setup if it is OK. I am 99% sure that the problem is not on the Android/app part.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help @Ogre_BGR.
I will ask for advise and then report my gained knowledge here.